# rspec expect to return false but doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

What a I missing here? I have a controller test for a very basic update function

```
context "where all is not well" do 
    before do 
      allow(mpu_instance).to receive(:save).and_return(false)
      patch :update, centre_id: venue_instance, id: 1
    end

    it "flashes an error" do 
      expect(flash[:error]).to_not be_nil
    end

    it " renders edit form again" do 
      expect(response).to render_template('admin/mpus/new')
    end
```

So in this block i am stubbing the save function to return false

```
  def update
    @mpu.update_attributes(params[:mpu])
    if @mpu.save
      flash[:notice]="changes saved"
      return redirect_to(edit_admin_centre_path(@mpuable))
    else
      flash[:error]="Check for errors"
      return redirect_to("admin/mpus/new")
    end
  end
```

Why on earth does it fail!?

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template('admin/mpus/edit')
   expecting <"admin/mpus/edit"> but rendering with <[]>

 Failure/Error: expect(flash[:error]).to_not be_nil
   expected: not nil
        got: nil
```

I cant see a logical explanation for this, as all the other tests that I stub to fail, do so in the correct way. I dont see what is so different about this one?

I am creating the instances via factory girl, so `'mpu_instance'` is `FactoryGirl.create :mpu_instance`

Comment: `mpu_instance` in your test is not the same object as `@mpu`.  They may be the same record but they're not the same object.  why don't you purposely fail the validation instead of stubbing?

Comment: @jvnill is right. You should use `allow(Mpu.any_instance).to receive(:save).and_return(false)` or stub `Mpu.stub(find: mpu_instance)`

Comment: I see but why would the exact same as I have done work on say the destroy function?! That passes. By the way your suggestion didnt change anything - test still failed

Comment: and it looks like your controller does not render view (it is default behavior). Add `render_views` ([doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views))